# Bash while loop ends execution when "ssh" is in loop body

Tags: bash, while-loop

Could anyone of you explain why the following bash **while** loop ends execution after the first iteration when `ssh` is executed in it's body, please?

**Input file**:

```
$ cat hosts
192.168.223.21     miner01
192.168.223.23     miner03
```

- While without ssh - two iterations:

```
$ while IFS=' ' read -r IP HOST; do echo "ip=$IP hostname=$HOST"; done < hosts
ip=192.168.223.21 hostname=miner01
ip=192.168.223.23 hostname=miner03
$
```

- While with ssh in body - **one iteration**:

```
$ while IFS=' ' read -r IP HOST; do echo "ip=$IP hostname=$HOST"; ssh $HOST hostname ; done < hosts
ip=192.168.223.21 hostname=miner01
miner01
$
```

I also executed it with `set -x` but I can't see the reason for such behavior:

```
$ while IFS=" " read -r IP HOST; do echo "ip=$IP hostname=$HOST"; ssh $HOST hostname; done < hosts
while IFS=" " read -r IP HOST; do echo "ip=$IP hostname=$HOST"; ssh $HOST hostname; done < hosts
+ IFS=' '
+ read -r IP HOST
+ echo 'ip=192.168.223.21 hostname=miner01'
ip=192.168.223.21 hostname=miner01
+ ssh miner01 hostname
miner01
+ IFS=' '
+ read -r IP HOST
$
```

**Bash version**:

```
$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh` also consumes standard input. Try to replace `ssh $HOST hostname` with `cat` or `nl`, to understand conceptually why it does not work. After the command consumes the input, `while` ends since there is nothing else to read.

Since you do not need `ssh` to consume stdin, redirect it. This works:

```
while IFS=" " read -r IP HOST; do
  echo "ip=$IP hostname=$HOST"
  ssh $HOST hostname < /dev/null
done < hosts
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation!
I added '-n' (it redirects stdin from /dev/null), which also solved this problem.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that also works. `< /dev/null` is just more general, in case someone has the same problem with something that is not `ssh`.